# Saved games in My Documents not working

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-installation, reinstall

I have a laptop system with Windows 8.1. I encountered a virus and decided to re-install Windows. I formatted the C drive and installed a fresh Windows 8.1 and installed drivers, etc.

I have a few games installed that I play occasionally. The games are installed in D drive and the saved games were in My Documents. I saved My Documents before installing Windows, and after installing Windows, I put the documents back, so the saved games were once again in the documents folder.

Now, I run the game and it should open my saved game. It doesn't; the game starts over to a fresh new game. My games start from 0% and I suspect the game is not reading the saved games in my documents folder.  It doesn't happen with one game only; I tried GTA V, Splinter Cell Blacklist, EA Cricket 07, and all three of these were unable to read the saved game files.

I have been installing Windows for a decade now and copying/pasting saved games ever since, too. Never did I face such issue. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. The Path was somehow redirected and it was not reading the files correctly.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Is there any detail you can add that might help someone else with a similar problem (what you discovered, how you diagnosed it, etc.)?